# How to find postorder on graph? (bfs-dfs)

Tags: data-structures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGD8T.png)

I need pre-order and post-order on this graph ty
I need pre-order and post-order on this graph ty
I need pre-order and post-order on this graph ty
I need pre-order and post-order on this graph ty
I need pre-order and post-order on this graph ty
I need pre-order and post-order on this graph ty
I need pre-order and post-order on this graph ty
I need pre-order and post-order on this graph ty